# How to assign a Django channel session to an object in ORM?

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

I have remote application that connects to the Django running Channels and opens websocket connection. I do not use Groups. The reason for opening websocket is only to have push notifications from Django.
If I want to push a notification to a websocket connection opened by an User, how to find the opened connection (its reply_channel)?

Answer (score 0):

With the default setting I could get the reply_channel string
In the websocket.connect handler:

```
channel = message.reply_channel.name
```

plus with the extended User model (user.channel) I could store that channel to particular user.

```
user = message.user
user.channel_string = channel
```

Then from HTTP I get for the particular user the user channel. This is a key for the Channel object got from the layer management:

```
from channels.channel import Channel

channel_string = user.channel_string
channel = Channel(channel_string)
channel.send(something)
```